# Убрать двойные границы у border

Tags: border

Есть две вкладки, у которых в активном состоянии, и при наведении есть border 1px solid, но нет в стандартном состоянии. Проблема в том, что border обеих вкладок, при наведении на соседнюю от активной, становится 2px.
Подскажите, как можно это исправить, не двигая блоки.

```css
.active,
.off {
  float: left;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.off {
  border: 0;
}

.off:hover {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button class="active">Активная</button>
  <button class="off">Вкладка</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При неактивной делать `border: 1px solid transparent`, а при активной `border-color: #000`, если я вас правильно понял. Для более точного описания проблемы, советую прикреплять часть кода.

Comment: Добавил код, посмотрите.

Comment: Я вас правильно понял, и вместо border: 0, сделайте border-color: transparent